# Mercurial: how to move a single directory between branches

Tags: mercurial, branch, swap

Hold on, this one's going to be rough.  I'm attempting to clean up a Mercurial repo that I can only describe as pathological, and it appears the simplest 'fix' is to swap *one directory* between two branches.  I'm not sure if I can adequately explain the situation, but I'll give it a shot.

We have a tool that generates raw source from a large set of input.  (Hundreds or thousands of input files, similar number of output files.)  This output is then hand-tweaked and optimized as needed, before being declared ready for deployment.  The tool is run inside a directory that offers the configuration files, etc.

Something like:

```
proj/.hg
    /input
    /output
    /config-env
```

Now, what has happened is that a branch was used for the tweaking, instead of the (to me) logical choice of a shared mq approach.  (The team wasn't aware of mq at the time, are mostly CVS trained, but to their credit, they *are* working to improve the workflow.)

Here's where it gets grody.

The named branch is the *raw output* branch, and the default branch is the *hand tweaked* branch.

The output of the tool was continually created, then `hg update raw`, then `hg merge`, to try and merge tool refinements to the output into the raw branch, then that was merged *back* into the 'default' branch to incorporate both the refinements and prior hand patches, using the merge failure list as the pick list for what needed to be further hand edited.

ie, there's this crazy cycle between the two branches that has made development a minor nightmare of fragility and errors.  That's what I'm trying to clean out.  What I want is for the default branch to be the raw output, and a new 'deploy' branch that contains the hand patches, with merges going only one way, from default to deploy. Still not optimal, IMO, but until I can convince the powers that be that mq is the way to go, it's a rather large improvement.

But.  There's more.  The config-env and input directories were altered as time went on, but the changes were not kept clean and in sync between the two branches.  The changes to the input and config-env are on the default branch, but the matching raw output is on the raw branch, with stale input and config-env that don't really belong there. I've inquired about removing the stale files as unnecessary, but there are some arguing that we need to retain them.  For that reason, I want to swap *only the output directory* between the two branches.

I considered something like `hg convert --branchmap swap.txt --filemap only-output.txt  --datesort` but then realized I would get only the output directory in the resulting repo.  I *might* be able to literally strip out the output directories from the two branches into their own repos with the branch names swapped, then merge the two repos together (no-output, output-with-swapped-branches), but I figured that perhaps someone on here would have a better idea.

Of course, what I'm aiming for is to have one branch with an mq patch list to store the hand patches, and that patch list be part of the shared repo, but babysteps are in order.

If push comes to shove, I think we can eliminate *most* of the history of the output directories on both branches, but we do require certain tagged releases to be retained on both branches.

Comment: If you're suggesting recent CSV refugees even look crosseyed at mq you're doing them a disservice.  There's no call for using mq in modern workflows at all.

Comment: I think there are legit uses for MQ, this just isn't one of them.

Comment: Although it isn't the question I'm asking, could you gentlemen provide a suggested alternative to mq as a longer term goal then?  Because the way it's being done is downright pathological.